# Slick slider - how to fix in for iphone?

Tags: css, ios, iphone, slick.js

On my android images in the slider look as they have to look, like squares, but on iphone it's something wrong, they look like that

[image]

I don't have any apple or mac devices. Why it is showing like that?
In my slick code is nothing special

```
jQuery('.upsells .products').slick({
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1, 
  dots: true,
  arrows:false,  
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1199,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,               
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,                      
      }
    },        
  ]
});
```

etc.
[The site itself](https://t80469.hostua04.fornex.host/product/svetodiodnyiy-trekovyiy-prozhektor-42w-vt/)

No codepen, cause the site is dynamic not static, all styles are in console.
I think it's some cross-browser issue, but I could find only very old info about iphone 5, not 11-12.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: useTransform: false to your settings

Comment: Hi there Edd could you please help me understand your answer more and provide a bit more about what you are suggesting to fix for this issue?